# Prove that $ (\sqrt{a_{n}})_{n=1}^{\infty}\rightarrow \sqrt{a} $ when $ (a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\rightarrow a $

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck on a homework question, and would be very thankful to anyone who helps. The question:

**Prove or disprove the following statement:**

**If:**   $ (a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is a series of positive numbers and $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\rightarrow a $

**Then:** $ (\sqrt{a_{n}})_{n=1}^{\infty}\rightarrow \sqrt{a} $

**Hint:** Distinguish between $a = 0$ and $a > 0$

OK, so I'm pretty sure that the statement is correct, I have the part for when a = 0 proved, but I'm stuck on the second part (when a > 0) I'm having "writer's block" and can't come up with any solution that would prove it...

Any hints and help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

**EDIT** - The series is a series of positive numbers

Comment: Do you know about continuous functions?

Comment: @JulienClancy: The question basically asks to prove that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is continuous, simply saying that it is won't work.

Comment: With this exercise you are proving that $\sqrt x$ is a continuous function. The proof is very much dependent on how $\sqrt x$ has been defined...

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add that the series is positive (all members are positive numbers) so x is always greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We'd like to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that $n > N \Rightarrow |\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}| < \varepsilon$. Given such an $\varepsilon$ we know there is $N$ such that $n > N \Rightarrow |a_n - a| < \varepsilon$. But what is $\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}$? We know $a_n - a = (\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a})(\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a})$. If $a > 0$ the you can bound the second factor by a positive constant (for you to find), call it $C$. Then take the absolute value of both sides, and let $N$ such that $n > N$ means $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon/C$.